# QR-Code generate and export to image file

Tags: c#

I used [QRCoder](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder) for generate QRCode.

```
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("Text to be encoded.", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
```

But I can not export and save my `qrCodeData`.

I tried the code below but can open file `result.png`

```
qrCodeData.SaveRawData("wwwroot/result.png", QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);
```

How can I export and save my QRCode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [official documentation](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder#usage):

> You only need five lines of code, to generate and view your first QR code.
>
> ```
> QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
> QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("The text which should be encoded.", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
> QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
> Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
> ```

So the solution is to use the `GetGraphic()` method to work with the `Bitmap` object. Also check https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/wiki/How-to-use-QRCoder

Comment: Thanks. I have read it quite carefully. But how can I save `qrCodeImage `?

Comment: @Alex With the [`Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Comment: I think code is not recommended to use now. As it will have issues with cross-platform such as on linux. For net 6.0, better use `SkiaSharp.QrCode` library